# While clicking the view it automatically selects the first Radiobutton in android

Tags: android

I have a view with `TextView` and `RadioButton`, if I click TextView first option in radio button gets selected automatically. I had also specified  `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` in layout and I'm using `Android 2.2.1` Versions. Any solution to this problem??

Answer (score 0):

Add the line to the xml

```
Clickable = false
```

I hope it solves the problem. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had also specified that, but it doesn't works for me.